# Getting Bad request 400 when testing API create method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, pytest

I am trying to test an API with pytest. I am getting a bad request 400 where I'd expect a status code 201.

There must be some error in how I set up the test data but I can't figure out where.

this is the data I am trying to send

```
graph_data =   {
        "project": "project1",
        "name": "Graph1",
        "nodes": [
            {
                "name": "Node1 of Graph 1",
                "graph": 1
            }
        ],
        "edges": [
            {
                "name": "EdgeForGraph1",
                "graph": 1,
                "source": 1,
                "target": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

And here my test:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestCreate:

    def setup(self):
        """Setup for tests to create user, graph, project and node

        """

        password = 'mypassword'
        username = 'testuser'
        project  = Project.objects.create(project_name='project1')
        graph    = Graph.objects.create(project=project, name='Graph1')
        node = Node.objects.create(graph=graph, name='node of Graph')
        source = Node.objects.create(graph=graph)
        target = Node.objects.create(graph=graph)
        user = User.objects.create_superuser(username=username, email='test@test.com',
                                             password=password)
        edge = Edge.objects.create(graph=graph, source=source, target=target)


    def test_aut_user_can_create_graph(self, client):
        headers = get_token(client)
        print(headers)
        create_data = graph_data
        print(create_data)
        url = api_reverse('create-graph')
        response = client.post(url, create_data, headers=headers)

        assert response.status_code == 201
```

the `get_token` method returns a token that I use to authenticate.

Here are my models:

```
class Graph(models.Model):
    project         = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    description     = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def nodes(self):
        return self.node_set.all()


    @property
    def edges(self):
        return self.edge_set.all()

class Node(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    graph           = models.ForeignKey(Graph, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Edge(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    graph           = models.ForeignKey(Graph, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source          = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='source_set')
    target          = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='target_set')
```

Maybe it's connected to the properties of edge and node?

It always gives me a `400 Bad Request` and I just don't know how to change it anymore. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The bad request means you make a bad request :) 
Maybe names should be the same? "Node1 of Graph 1" is not equal what you request

Comment: hehe yes I know that somehow I am sending a bad request. I was hoping someone could help me figure out why the request is bad. Thanks so much for the tip on the name.... It still doesn't work though.... Also I am testing a create method for the graph. So shouldn't I be able to send whatever data? I mean I create it anew.... Also the same request works fine when I test it manually

Comment: Start with analyzing `response.message` on error, e.g. `assert response.status_code == 201, response.message`. It may be also called `response.errors`, not sure about the right name. Also, what is the `client` - is it Django's `TestClient` or DRF's `APIClient`? Django's test client will send multipart data by default; you have to explicitly specify the content type in headers for it to serialize data to JSON string. The DRF client does that by default AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you very much hoefling! It turned out that I had to rewrite my whole view because it didn't allow for double nested serializer.... Once I had my view rewritten I adapted the test and it works

Comment: whoever downvotes me please let me know why....